# Flutter - Deserialize firebase_messagin notification using json_serializable

Tags: json, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using [Json_serializable](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/json_serializable) on all my models in my app (it gives a fromJson and a toJson method automaticly to my models with a command line).

Every (de)serializations are working perfectly but not with the firebase_messaging json.

Here is what I do :

```
onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> msg) {
  FCMNotification fcmNotification = FCMNotification.fromJson(msg);
}
```

And I always have this kind of error :

> Type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Map < dynamic, dynamic>' in type cast

Or

> '_InternalLinkedHashMap< dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map< String, dynamic>'

I have seen this kind of issue in github [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16589), but I didn't find any solution for me. Help please

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have found the problem and the solution.

Firebase Cloud Messaging notifications are received as a Map.

The structure of the map is like :

```
{
"registration_ids": ["registrationID1, "registrationID2", ...],
"notification": {
  "title": "New message",
  "body": "new message in channel: test"
},
"data": {
  "type": "CHANNEL_MESSAGE",
  "author": {
    "id": 5,
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Doe",
    "email": "J.doe@email.com",
    "userType": "USER",
    "language": "EN"
  },
}
```

}

We can put what we want in "data". In my case, I have an Author objet. 
This object make an additional level in the map. **Firebase Cloud Messaging considers that all additionnal levels values are String.**

So, we can deserialize 'data' with traditionnal 'fromJson(json)' method, but if we want to deserialize 'author', we have to decode Json first, like that :

```
String jsonAuthorStr = msg["data"]["author"];
Map<String, dynamic> temp = json.decode(jsonAuthorStr);
```

Then, deserialize :

```
Author author = Author.fromJson(temp);
```

Comment: I wonder, sometimes it converts the num and bools to strings.. I wonder